# string.Format to display only first n (2) digits in a number

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a mouse move coordinate,

For example:

```
s = string.Format("{0:D4},{1:D4}", nx, ny);

the result s is "0337,0022"
```

the question is how to show only two digits in front only?

I would like to get:

```
s is "03,00"
```

Here is another example:

```
s = "0471,0306"
```

I want to be:

```
s = "04,03"
```

and when the coordinate is "-"

example

s = "-0471,0306"

I want to be:

```
s = "-04,03"
```

Comment: I do not believe this can be done merely with standard format strings. i.e.: might have to convert to a string *first* and then take the relevant portion(s).

Comment: If `nx` is 12345, do you want `12` as your output or `123`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the string on the comma and then sub-string the first two characters of each portion, like this:

```
string result = String.Empty;
string s = String.Format("{0:D4},{1:D4}", nx, ny);
string[] values = s.Split(',');

int counter = 0;
foreach (string val in values)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int digitsCount = 0;

    // Loop through each character in string and only keep digits or minus sign
    foreach (char theChar in val)
    {
        if (theChar == '-')
        {
            sb.Append(theChar);
        }

        if (Char.IsDigit(theChar))
        {
            sb.Append(theChar);
            digitsCount += 1;
        }

        if (digitsCount == 2)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    result += sb.ToString();

    if (counter < values.Length - 1)
    {
        result += ",";
    }

    counter += 1;
}
```

Note: This will work for any amount of comma separated values you have in your `s` string.

Comment: If nx or ny  is less 10 than this will result in an IndexOutOfRange exception.  It will also not produce the output the OP wants for numbers < 1000.  337 will display as "37" not "03".

Comment: @Alexbelek - What were the values of nx and ny in your example that gave you the result of "0259,001825,18"?

Comment: @KarlAnderson - sory . my s string value before is 0259,0018 so i put your code an the value is "0259,001825,18". your value now is 25,18 . but i want value is "02,00".

Comment: So there is no `nx` or `ny` number values? It is just one string with a comma separating the two values?

Comment: for example my `nx = "0259"; ny = 0018` i need the value is two digit first. so the value is 02 and 00 , Or . 02,00 .

Comment: I have updated my answer, I completely misunderstood what you wanted originally, sorry.

Comment: what if the coordinate is - . example my s now is -0018,0193 so, the value is -00,01 . your value is -0,01 .

Comment: @Alexbelek - ok, I added a check for digits in my answer.

Comment: @KarlAnderson -  error `Error 41 A local variable named 'c' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'c', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else `

Comment: Do you have a variable named `c` earlier in your program? Updating answer and changing variable `c` to `theChar`.

Comment: @KarlAnderson - yes im forgot i have variable c before. i try with your code, when s is -0018,0193 your value now is 00,01 , the "-" not show.

Comment: yes it solved thank you so much. but why must use substring? @shf301 answer is worked but without substring and "-".

Answer (score 3):

```
s =string.Format("{0},{1}",  
                 string.Format("{0:D4}", nx).Substring(0,2), 
                 string.Format("{0:D4}", ny).Substring(0,2));
```

Comment: @Naren have you test? there will not be a exception but it will give "00,00" output

Comment: ,Sorry I forgot the D4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that nx and ny are integers

```
s = nx.ToString("D4").Substring(0,2)        // leftmost digits
  + ny.ToString("D4").Substring(0,2)        // leftmost digits
```

"D4" ensure the size of the string that must be enought for substring boundaries

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
Func<int, string> f = n => n.ToString("D4").Substring(0, 2);
var s = string.Format("{0},{1}", f(nx), f(ny));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the number before you use Substring.

```
        var s1 = nx.ToString();
        var s2 = ny.ToString();
        // Checks if the number is long enough
        string c1 = (s1.Count() > 2) ? s1.Substring(0, 2) : s1;
        string c2 = (s2.Count() > 2) ? s2.Substring(0, 2) : s2;
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",c1,c2);
```